# Cannot connect to my website running on Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, portforwarding

I cannot seem to connect to my website running on Azure VM. I have looked through every single Azure docs.

I allowed incoming connections to port 80 per documentation:
[image]

I have a very basic Hello World nodejs app listening on port 80 (i confirmed this app works locally my own system):

[image]

I am attempting to connect to the site via the Public IP assigned to me that i see in Azure Portal:
[image]

The problem is any attempt to connect to 40.XXX.XXX.230:80 in Chrome simply times out.

I am new to VM's but i think something is wrong with port forwarding?

Comment: You need also check if there is just one NSG. Sometimes the subnet and VM nic in two different NSG. And the firewall in the VM local is also a point need to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another thing to check:

Remote desktop into the virtual machine, and confirm that the virtual machine's local firewall allows incoming HTTP and HTTPS connections.

[image: Image of Windows Defender Firewall]

Comment: Thank you, you are correct! It seems crazy to me that AWS does not highlight this fact more, especially considering hosting a web server on a VM is so widely used.

Comment: Hi Andrew, can you explain in more details how I add HTTP and HTTPs to the inbound rules?  I have used RDP to access the firewall settings, but there is no option to add a specific rule for HTTP and HTTPs.  What am I doing wrong?